# How do I manipulate shapes within a zoomed panel in Java?

Tags: java, swing, scroll, graphics, mouseover

I have some code I found on the internet that allows me to control zooming and panning of a scrollable panel in Java but I want to be able to manipulate the shapes within this area and having trouble translating the x and y coordinates back to the original (unzoomed) dimensions ..

There are a few things I would like to do with these shapes but to start, how can I paint the two entity rectangles red when the mouse moves within them?

Here is code I have so far:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class CanvasPane extends JPanel {

    private static Canvas canvas;

    public CanvasPane(boolean isDoubleBuffered) {
        super(isDoubleBuffered);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        canvas = new Canvas(1.0);
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(canvas);
        pane.getViewport().setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Graphics");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(new CanvasPane(true), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
  
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //Initial scrolling of the canvas to its center
        Rectangle canvasRectangle = canvas.getBounds();
        Rectangle visibleRectangle = canvas.getVisibleRect();
        double tx = (canvasRectangle.getWidth() - visibleRectangle.getWidth())/2;
        double ty = (canvasRectangle.getHeight() - visibleRectangle.getHeight())/2;
        visibleRectangle.setBounds((int)tx, (int)ty, visibleRectangle.width, visibleRectangle.height);
        canvas.scrollRectToVisible(visibleRectangle);
    }
}

class Canvas extends JComponent implements MouseWheelListener, MouseMotionListener, MouseListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private double zoom = 1.0;
    public static final double SCALE_STEP = 0.1d;
    private Dimension initialSize;
    private Point origin;
    private double previousZoom = zoom;
    private double scrollX = 0d;
    private double scrollY = 0d;
    private Rectangle2D workspace = new Rectangle2D.Double(0,0, 1024, 768);
    
    private Rectangle entity1 = new Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 100);
    private Rectangle entity2 = new Rectangle(300, 300, 100, 100);

    public Canvas(double zoom) {
        this.zoom = zoom;
        addMouseWheelListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        addMouseListener(this);
        setAutoscrolls(true);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)workspace.getWidth(), (int)workspace.getHeight()));
    }

    @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        //Zoom graphics
        g2d.scale(zoom, zoom);

        //translate graphics to be always in center of the canvas
        Rectangle size = getBounds();
        double tx = ((size.getWidth() - workspace.getWidth() * zoom) / 2) / zoom;
        double ty = ((size.getHeight() - workspace.getHeight() * zoom) / 2) / zoom;
        g2d.translate(tx, ty);

        //Draw
        g2d.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g2d.fill(workspace);
                       
        g2d.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5.0f));
        g2d.draw(workspace);
        
        g2d.draw(entity1);
        g2d.draw(entity2);        
    }

    @Override public void setSize(Dimension size) {
        super.setSize(size);
        if (initialSize == null) {
            this.initialSize = size;
        }
    }

    @Override public void setPreferredSize(Dimension preferredSize) {
        super.setPreferredSize(preferredSize);
        if (initialSize == null) {
            this.initialSize = preferredSize;
        }
    }

    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
        double zoomFactor = -SCALE_STEP * e.getPreciseWheelRotation() * zoom;
        zoom = Math.abs(zoom + zoomFactor);
        
        //Here we calculate new size of canvas relative to zoom.
        Dimension d = new Dimension(
                (int)(initialSize.width * zoom),
                (int)(initialSize.height * zoom));
            setPreferredSize(d);
            setSize(d);
            validate();
        followMouseOrCenter(e.getPoint());
        previousZoom = zoom;
    }

    public void followMouseOrCenter(Point2D point) {
        Rectangle size = getBounds();
        Rectangle visibleRect = getVisibleRect();
        scrollX = size.getCenterX();
        scrollY = size.getCenterY();
        
        if (point != null) {
            scrollX = point.getX() / previousZoom * zoom - (point.getX() - visibleRect.getX());
            scrollY = point.getY() / previousZoom * zoom - (point.getY() - visibleRect.getY());
        }

        visibleRect.setRect(scrollX, scrollY, visibleRect.getWidth(), visibleRect.getHeight());
        scrollRectToVisible(visibleRect);
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        if (origin != null) {
            int deltaX = origin.x - e.getX();
            int deltaY = origin.y - e.getY();
            Rectangle view = getVisibleRect();
            view.x += deltaX;
            view.y += deltaY;
            scrollRectToVisible(view);
        }
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        origin = new Point(e.getPoint());
    }
       
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {


    }
    
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

I have tried to calculate using following code but this isn't quite right

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

    double x = e.getX() / zoom;
    double y = e.getY() / zoom;

    double x2 = getWidth() - workspace.getWidth() * zoom; 
    double y2 = getHeight() - workspace.getHeight() * zoom; 
    
    if(x2 > 0) x -= x2;
    if(y2 > 0) y -= y2;
    
    Point p = new Point((int)x, (int)y);
    
    if(entity1.contains(p)) {
        intersects = true;
    } 
    else {
        intersects = false;
    }       
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: *but to start, how can I paint the two entity rectangles red when the mouse moves within them?* - first you need to restructure your code a bit. 1) you need to keep an ArrayList of objects that you want to paint. 2) The object in the ArrayList will need information about the Shape you want to paint and the Color you want to paint. Then your paintComponent() method will just iterate through the ArrayList and paint each object. See the `DrawOnComponent` example from [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/).

Comment: One that is changed. you will then be able to use the ArrayLIst to determine when a mouse have moved over a shape. First you would need to adjust the mouse point by the zoom factor then you would iterate through the ArrayList to find a Shape that contains the mouse point. Then you change the color and repaint.

Comment: That works if I dont do a zoom ... but once I zoom, it doesnt work anymore ... I tried mutliplying with the zoom value but that didn't work either ....  I guess I need to do this translation in the MouseMove method but unsure of the calculation

Comment: I can't believe you made all those suggested changes in 6 minutes. What debugging did you do within that 6 minutes? Maybe you need to "divide" by the zoom factor? Look at the values that you calculate and see if they make sense?

Comment: I put a "CLICK" print statement like so:    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

     if(entity1.contains(e.getPoint())) {
      System.out.println("CLICK");
     } 
     else {
      System.out.println("MISS");
     }     
    }    i'll try the divide ....

Comment: I don't see where you "adjust" the mouse point by the zoom factor in that code. You just take the value directly from the MouseEvent. And you should get a message at some point when you move the mouse over the entire frame. The problem may just be that your adjustment is incorrect so you need to find the proper adjustment factor.

Comment: I tried this       public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

 
     double x = e.getX() / zoom;
     double y = e.getY() / zoom;
     Point p = new Point((int)x, (int)y);
     
     if(entity1.contains(p)) {
      System.out.println("CLICK");
     } 
     else {
      System.out.println("MISS");
     }     
    }

Comment: I don't care what your tried? You tell us what the problem is. You know the value of your entity is fixed. So know you need to display your calculated value as your move the mouse to see what is displayed. Then as you get closer/farther away from the entity you see how your calculated value is changing to see if it makes sense. First try this without the zoom factor. Then try it with the zoom factor to see if it is more reasonable. Maybe you also need to account for the translation of the panel in the scrollpane? I don't know what the exact formula is.

Comment: Yes, I am getting closer ... Dividing by the zoom will only work when the scrollbars are present but not when they are absent ....Just trying to figure out the rest via trial and error ... thanks camicker ...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work even better but I am not sure if its the cleanest solution ...

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

    double x = e.getX() / zoom;
    double y = e.getY() / zoom;

//  double x2 = getWidth() - workspace.getWidth() * zoom; 
//  double y2 = getHeight() - workspace.getHeight() * zoom; 
        
    double x2 = ((getWidth() - workspace.getWidth() * zoom) / 2) / zoom;
    double y2 = ((getHeight() - workspace.getHeight() * zoom) / 2) / zoom;

    
    
    if(x2 > 0) x -= x2;
    if(y2 > 0) y -= y2;
    
    Point p = new Point((int)x, (int)y);
    
    if(entity1.contains(p)) {
        intersects = true;
    } 
    else {
        intersects = false;
    }       
    repaint();
}
```